# MSBuild for Delphi 2010 creates empty Dcp directory in drive's root directory

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-2010

I'm using MSBuild to build Delphi 2010 projects. It works fine. The only problem I have is that it creates 2 empty directories (Bpl and Dcp) in drive's root directory.

Is there any way to prevent MSBuild from creating these directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with either the

```
Project|Options|Delphi Compiler|Output directory or Package output directory
```

configuration, or the

```
Tools|Options|Delphi Options|Package output directory or DCP output directory
```

. You might check to see if you somehow have those set to the root of the drive or simply to .

FWIW, I use MSBuild from the commandline quite often, and I've never seen a DCP or BPL directory created anywhere I didn't specifically ask for them. I'm pretty sure this is simply a configuration issue in one of the path settings I mentioned above.

Comment: The problem was BDSCOMMONDIR variable. It wasn't set by our .groupproj file.

Comment: @krzysiek drozdz: Thanks for the update. It'll help people that run into this issue in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a Delphi bug to me. Have you contacted them regarding this?

Comment: If it's MS Build creating them, it's either an issue with MS Build or an issue with the project configuration. Neither of those would be a "Delphi bug".